# How can I achieve automatic login to the nomachine web client without providing access credentials？

Tags: authentication, nomachine

When I use the nomachine web client, I have to enter a user name and password each time, which is a tedious step for me. I have tried to modify files such as server.cfg, web.cfg and default.nxs according to some tips on the official website, but failed. Is there anyone familiar with nomachine who can tell me how to solve this problem?Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Nothing in your question says it has anything to do with the Ubuntu OS. This seems like a question you should be asking the nomachine web client people.

Answer (score 0):

Tick the checkbox *Save my login credentials* when prompted. The next time you will just log in without providing them.

Comment: I checked that button, but I still had to click log in every time I reconnected to the remote desktop